# Redirecting errors *from redirection operations themselves*

Tags: bash, file, stdout, io-redirection, stderr

Let us say I have some file called a.txt in the current directory. It's chmod value is 000.

Therefore, if I try to write to it, I get the following output:

```
> printf "Hello" >> a.txt
-bash: a.txt: Permission denied
```

How can I suppress this output? I have tried appending `2>/dev/null` to my command, but this redirection does not seem to work as I had originally hoped.

Comment: BTW, do you want your program to still run, rather than silently not being invoked at all? For `printf`, obviously, there's no point to running it if it can't write to stdout; but I could think of some cases where there might be other side effects you'd actually want.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy For my purposes, this will be in a bash script that hides most output and uses print statements to explain the general idea of what is going on. This printf is part of an if statement, and if the write fails, then the user is told that the write failed and to contact me before exiting with a code of 1.

Comment: Gotcha. As an aside, informational and diagnostic information should generally be printed to stderr rather than stdout. That's not just a matter of following [POSIX conventions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stdin.html), but also makes sure that your logs still show up in the right place if your stdout is piped elsewhere, and ensures that those logs are printed immediately rather than buffered (as stdout is buffered by default when printed to a non-TTY destination -- why content doesn't show up immediately in such cases is something of a FAQ around here).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The answer by that other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62685959/14122) is correct if you also want to suppress errors *from the command you're running*, not just from the redirections performed before starting it.

If you want to *only* suppress messages from the redirection itself and not also suppress error messages from actual execution, then you need an extra pair of redirections, to temporarily store the original value of stderr so you can later restore it:

```
printf "Hello" 3>&2 2>/dev/null >>a.txt 2>&3 3>&-
```

This breaks down as follows:

- `3>&2` copies the original stderr (FD 2) to a file descriptor that is unused by default (FD 3), creating a backup of the original destination.
- `2>/dev/null` then points stderr to `/dev/null`.
- `>>a.txt` points stdout (FD 1) to `aa.txt`, with stderr pointing to `/dev/null`.
- `2>&3` copies our backup on FD 3 back to FD 2, restoring stderr to its original destination so the program being run can log errors.
- `3>&-` deletes the backup, leaving the file descriptor table as it would have been if we'd done nothing at all. (It's generally safe to leave this out -- most well-behaved programs will simply ignore nonstandard file descriptors' initial values unless explicitly told to do otherwise).

Comment: Excellent answer.  Worth noting that if you're running interactively you might want to simplify to:  `cmd  2> /dev/null > output 2> /dev/tty`

Comment: Clever. @thatotherguy's comment was all I needed for my purposes, but I will certainly be noting this down for future reference!

Comment: Thank you! And by the way, this was a great first question! Self-contained while remaining terse; well-formatted, not a FAQ we see over and over, describes what you tried, &c.

Answer (score 2):

The redirections are evaluated in order, so to suppress the message you have to redirect stderr *before* you attempt to redirect stdout:

```
printf "Hello" 2> /dev/null >> a.txt
```